# Why does Windows 8.1 file explorer crash after I click the default icon?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-8.1

When I click on the default taskbar icon (as opposed to the pinned icons accessible through right-click) it seems like metro crashes and restarts. I tried to edit the default launch folder but it seems like no account on the system has permission to do so.

So, why does Windows 8.1 file explorer crash after I click the default icon?

Comment: please generate the crash dumps and upload them: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Autodesk Inventor 2014, or any Inventor Program created before 2013. If that's the case download the new service pack for Inventor from Autodesk.

Comment: Yea that was it ty